# The rotations that transform one circle onto another in an Euclidean affine space of dimension 3?

Tags: geometry

In the Euclidean affine space of dimension three, we have two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ of the same radius and non-coplanar axes, how to determine all rotations that transform $C_1$ onto $C_2$ ?

I found that there is only one rotation, I am not sure if my proof is correct:
A rotation that maps circle $C_1$ onto circle $C_2$ must map the center $O_1$ of $C_1$ onto the center $O_2$ of $C_2$. Its axis must therefore be orthogonal to the line joining the two centers and equally distant from them. And given such an axis, the rotation about it that maps $O_1$ to $O_2$ is unique. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good idea to express the centers' transfer. Another idea is to take account of the axes' transfer (axis of a 3D circle = set of points that are at the same distance from all points of the circle).

Comment: A question : how do you represent a 3D rotation in affine euclidean space ? Under the form $V \to RV+T$ where $R$ is a euclidean rotation and $T \in \mathbb R^3$ ?

Comment: What happens if the circles share a center?

Comment: With *"non-coplanar"*, are you also excluding parallel circles?

Answer (score 1):

For any rotation, we need an axis of rotation, a point $p_0$ that lies on the axis of rotation, and a rotation angle $\theta$.  The axis of rotation and $\theta$ will determine the rotation matrix $R$ that together with $p_0$ determines the image of rotation of various vectors.

The matrix $R$ is given by

$R = a a^T + (I - a a^T) \cos \theta + S_a \sin \theta $

The above equation is known as the [Rodriguez rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula).  See also [here](https://www.planetmath.org/RodriguesRotationFormula).

Where $a$ is a unit vector along the axis of rotation, and the skew-symmetrix matrix is given by

$S_a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - a_z && a_y \\ a_z && 0 && - ax \\ -a_y && a_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

From the properties of rotation, we know that if $v_2 = R v_1 $ then the axis of rotation is perpendicular to the vector $(v_2 - v_1)$.

In this problem, we have two pairs of vectors, the first pair is related by,

$O_2 = p_0 + R (O_1 - p_0)$

So that $ (O_2 - p_0) = R (O_1 - p_0) $

and also we have $n_2 = R n_1$ , where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the unit vectors perpendicular to the planes of the circles.

Hence, the axis of rotation is perpendicular to $(O_2 - O_1)$ and also perpendicular to $n_2 - n_1$, therefore, we have to take the axis of rotation to be the unit vector along the cross product $(O_2 - O_1) \times (n_2 - n_1) $.

So, we have the axis $a$ now.  Next, we want to find the angle of rotation, and for that we can project the vectors $n_1$ and $n_2$ onto the plane $a^T v = 0 $, the angle of rotation is the angle between the projections of $n_1$ and $n_2$ onto this plane.

With this, the matrix $R$ is now fully specified.  But we still have to determine a point $p_0$ where the axis passes.  So we write

$O_2 - p_0 = R (O_1 - p_0) $

from which,

$ (I - R) p_0 = O_2 - R O_1 $

This system of three equation in three variables (the coordinated of $p_0$) is rank deficient, meaning that the matrix $(I - R)$ has only two independent rows, and its determinant is zero.  So the solution to the system will be a whole line of the form $p_0 = x_0 + t x_1 $ where $t$ is arbitrary, and $x_1$ is along the axis of rotation $a$ found above.

Any $p_0$ on this line is acceptable.

Now the rotation is fully specified, and as the author of the question mentioned, it is unique.

Comment: @Kamal, I've updated my solution.

Comment: A precision for the OP : formula $R=aa^T+...$ can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) (Rodrigues rotation formula).

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie, I've updated my solution to reflect your remark.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with your reasoning. Your problem is that saying "*Its axis must therefore be orthogonal to the line joining the two centers and equally distant from them.*"doesn't determine a *unique* line (rotation axis). In fact, if $P$ is the perpendicular bissector plane of the line segment joining the two centers, $\color{red}{any}$ line belonging to plane $P$ could be a candidate for being this "axis".

Here is the way I would consider the issue:

A) Existence of such a rotation.

Let us use the following notations for circles $C_1,C_2$: $O_1,O_2$ for their centers and $U_1, U_2$ resp. for the unit normal vectors of their planes.

Consider two steps:

1. First step: operate on circle $C_1$ the translation by vector $\vec{O_1O_2}$ sending $O_1$ onto $O_2$. In this way, the image of the first circle and the second circle belong to a same sphere.
2. Second step: use rotation $R$ bringing $U_1$ onto $U_2$. The rotation axis is directed by cross product $U_3:=U_1 \times U_2$ and its angle is $\theta:=\operatorname{arccos}(U_1.U_2)$. This rotation can be expressed, using unit vector $a=U_3/\|U_3\|$ by Rodrigues formula (which can be found in the other answer):

$$R = a a^T + (I - a a^T) \cos \theta + S_a \sin \theta$$

B) $\color{red}{NON-Unicity \ }$ of this solution:

The (affine space) rotation found above can be combined with a rotation that - say - transforms the second circle into itself.

Here is an example of cases where two different affine rotations

$$V \to RV+U \tag{1}$$

transforms the blue circle (center in $(0,0,0)$, axis Oz, radius 1) into the cyan circle (center in $(1,1,1)$, axis parallel to Ox, radius 1)(see figure) where

$$R=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{or} \ \ R=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1\\c&c&0\\c&-c&0\end{pmatrix} \ (c=\sqrt{2}/2)$$

$$\text{and} \ U=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

[image]

Comment: Your solution is totally correct.  I complicated things for myself by assuming that the transformation cannot include a translation, and that it is a pure rotation.

Comment: However, I did not say that the axis is unique based on $\{O_1, O_2\}$ only.  What I used was the pair $\{ O_1, O_2 \}$ as well as the pair $\{n_1, n_2 \}$ (which you call $\{ U_1, U_2 \}$).

Comment: @GeometryLover About your second remark: my comment was directed to Kamal, the asker, not to you !

Comment: Yes I see now what you mean.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I just added a counterexample.